# copy field in schema of solr is not working

Tags: solr

This is schema.xml file implementation of copy field

```
<copyField source="UniversityName" dest="_text_"/>
<copyField source="UniversityName" dest="_text_"/>
<copyField source="UniversityLocation" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="UniversityWebLink" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="DegreeLink" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="UniversityName" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="DegreeName" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="UniversityType" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="ProgramType" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="ProgramTypeLink" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="ProgramCatagory" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="FacultyName" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="FacultyLink" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="Email" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
<copyField source="ContactPerson" dest="_text_" maxChars="256"/>
```

This is config.xml implementation of default search field

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
  <!-- Default search field-->
     <str name="df">_text_</str>
```

I have modified scema.xml file and config file of my collection in solr. But the copy field is not working.why is it? what is the solution?
When I directly give the fieldname in config.xml file it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my checklist when this kind of problem occurs. Please check.

1. Make sure you saved all the edited config files and reload core or restart server.
2. Check whether source fields are having data or not?
3. Then reindex your data and see you are getting results or not.
4. Make sure the source field itself is not getting data from any other copyfield.
   Because Solr will not support chaining. Here is a reference from Solr documentation.

> Copying is done at the stream source level and no copy feeds into
>   another copy. This means that copy fields cannot be chained i.e. you
>   cannot copy from here to there and then from there to elsewhere.
>   However, the same source field can be copied to multiple destination
>   fields:

`<copyField source="here" dest="there"/>` `<copyField source="here" dest="elsewhere"/>.`

4. If you like to see copied content on the destination field make the destination fields stored property value to true on schema.xml and reload core then index and see. It may help you to understand what exactly happens when using copyfield. In our case whether data is populated on dest field or not.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I have taken a collection where the copy field is working in another solr and pasted it in my solr. That was worked.After when i created a new collection in my solr the copy field worked without any problem.I still don't know what was happened inside.Do u have any idea?

Comment: HI, Sorry for the delayed response. Could you please post with the configs you are trying which will help us to identify the problem.